How do I prevent XML::LibXML making <style> CDATA?
Let's just say I don't want this to happen to my <style> tag:
./ph nongdi.html | grep style nongdi.html -
nongdi.html: <style>
nongdi.html: </style>
(standard input): <style><![CDATA[
(standard input): ]]></style>

Yes, I read Should I use <![CDATA[...]]> in HTML5? but that's beside the point.
What am I doing wrong?
$ cat ph
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::LibXML;
use strict;
use warnings q(all);
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new( no_cdata => 1 );
my $dom    = $parser->load_html( location => shift );
print $dom->toString();


You talk of HTML, but you produce XML. Maybe you want ->toStringHTML?

toStringHTML works great! Thanks. However now all my UTF-8 has become entities. Yes, they still render in the browser, but make the source HTML look terrible.

I see. I now need to add:
use HTML::Entities;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
print decode_entities $dom->toStringHTML();

That's not safe either.
